# Как с помощью selenium закрывать окна?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

С помощью selenium открываю страницу, на ней есть другие страницы, по которым требуется перейти и собрать информацию, но на эти другие страницы не даны ссылки, потому приходится с помощью .click() переходить по ним, с этим все ок, но они открываются в новом окне, как можно после сбора информации закрывать каждое такое окно. driver.quit(), driver.close() закрывают весь драйвер, а мне нужно закрывать только появляющееся новое окно, далее переходить к другому и т.д. иначе их наоткрывается очень много... Спасибо.

Comment: закрывайте текущую активную вкладку

Comment: скажите, пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Comment: https://paveltashev.medium.com/python-and-selenium-open-focus-and-close-a-new-tab-4cc606b73388

Comment: но новое открывающееся окно у нас и становится же активным сразу, разве нет?  Мне не требуется перейти на страницу, там открыть первую ссылку, она откроется в новом окне, далее получить информацию и закрыть это окно, потом открыть 2 ссылку и т.д, а уже в конце закрыть сам драйвер

Comment: У меня при переходе по ссылке открывается не новая вкладка, а именно новое окно браузера, по ссылке, что вы прислали, к сожалению, немного другое...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить все окна -> list:

```
windows = driver.window_handles
```

Получить текущее окно -> str:

```
window = driver.current_window_handle
```

Переключение на окно:

```
driver.switch_to_window(window)
```

Закрыть окно:

```
driver.close()
```

> Если у вас только одно окно, то браузер закроется, eсли вы хотите закрыть все окна вместе с браузером `driver.quit()`

Comment: Подскажите,пожалуйста, зачем на нужно выполнять первую строку? windows = driver.window_handles, она же потом не используется нигде? У меня 2 окна и такое чувство, что переключается наоборот на предыдущее окно. И уже распаршивается оно, а не новое. Если без ваших рекомендаций делаю, то переключения на первоначальное окно вроде нет, судя по ChromeDriver, но распаршивается также именно первое окно, а не новое.

Comment: Первая команда возвращает список всех окон. Перед тем как закрывать ненужные window = driver.current_window_handle(возвращает id текущего окна) и с помощью if и цикла закройте остальные